# Yii - How to build a model for a form wrapping a doule entry table

Tags: forms, yii, model

I have a doubt. Is there a way where I can create a Yii model for a form wrapping a double entry table?

My issue is that the fields are dynamic so you can have 100 columns and 100 rows, so create fields manually is impossible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a CFormModel subclass

Comment: Thanks for your answer